# Electron does not open the requested url

Tags: electron

I'm new to Electron.js, I just did the initial configurations of Electron and I'm trying to open a URL, the problem is that when I run npm start it opens the following and not the page of the url, how do I solve it?

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    })
    win.loadURL('https://www.google.com/')
}
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow the [Electron Quickstart](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start) and replace `win.loadFile('index.html')` with `win.loadURL('https://google.com')`.